# How to change element properties on hover with CSS in following case

Tags: html, css, hover

I got some webpage element that reacts on mouse hover over picture with overlay sliding-in, I also want to get same effect when user hovers blue div with text below picture. Is that possible only with css?

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pn8Z/10/

HTML

```
        <div class="rt_tiletext">
            <p>
                wards are focused oni wards are focused oni
                wards ards are focused oni wards areds are focused
                oni wards are focused oni wards are focused oni 
                wards are focused oni wards are focu wards are focused i .
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rt_tilewrap {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: rgba( 22, 255, 22, 0.3);
    width:355px;
}

.rt_tiletext {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    color: #666666;
    float:left;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    text-align: justify;
    display: block;
    background:skyblue;
}

.rt_tiletext p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.rt_timg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

.rt_imgwrap{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.rt_tileoverlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255,0,  0.5);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    z-index: 100;
}

.rt_imgwrap:hover > .rt_tileoverlay {
     width:355px;
}
```

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: Could you clarify which element (by classname, I guess) should be hovered over and which one should be modified? It's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS so that the effect is applied when hovering over the parent element, `.rt_tilewrap`. In doing so, the transition appears to be activated on hover of `.rt_imgwrap` and `.rt_tiletext`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9pn8Z/11/)

```
.rt_tilewrap:hover .rt_tileoverlay {
    width:355px;
}
```

In an instance like this, you aren't able to use the general sibling selector, `~` or the adjacent selector, `+`, as they don't select previous elements. Therefore the easiest solution would be to add the effect on `:hover` of the parent element. Alternatively, JavaScript would be necessary as it has the ability to select transverse elements in the DOM.